# set ngModel value dynamically in Angular2

Tags: angularjs, ng-grid, angular-ngmodel, ngfor

is there is  a way in which I can set the value of ngModel dynamically ? for example

```
<h1>please fill the text</h1>
<div *ngFor="#value of columnsNames">
    {{value }}<input type = "text" [(ngModel)]="SomeDynamicValue">
</div>
```

Comment: you can do it by using controller

Comment: can you please explain to me how I can do it ?

Answer (score 1):

```
<div *ngFor="#value of columnsNames">
    {{value }}<input type = "text" [(ngModel)]="SomeDynamicValue[value]">
</div>
```